# Why do I need to removeChild form input to call custom GAE API

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, google-app-engine

All I want to do is pass a string to a stupid simple GAE endpoints API that just returns what I sent it. For learning purposes I want to do it without using the Google Javascript libraries or Jinja, Flask, Webapp2, etc. OBTW, yes, I know about the API Explorer. The apparent simplicity of the request there got me wondering how to do it without using the API Explorer.

The code below is not great, it's just for checking out the API. (and yes, I started with the Google Tac-Tac-Toe example)

In my Javascript you'll see `form1.removeChild(input1)`. After trying to build the query string using the value in an `<input type=text>`; I found that removing the child element (the `<input type=text>`) from the form got it to work like the basic static URL (which is the second form element in the HTML below).

If the child input element is not removed I get the following error on the local dev GAE server.

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Looking at the request header on the Chrome Developer Tools I see that the headers are the same for the two forms. The difference is that the first one has Form-Data and the second one does not. Both have a query string.

**I have two questions:**
Is there a way to set up the Endpoints API to handle the Form-Data w/o the GAE JS library?

Using just JS, is there another way to do this that's cleaner? Meaning, where the Form-Data does not need to be deleted.

The GAE Javascript Library is the right way to go I get that. Again, I'm just trying to make sure I understand the basics here.

Here's the API (Python):

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import remote, messages

CLIENT_ID = '[from the developer console]'

class StubMessageIn(messages.Message):
   tell_me = messages.StringField(1)

@endpoints.api(name='tictactoe',
           version='v1',
           allowed_client_ids=[CLIENT_ID],
           audiences=[CLIENT_ID])
class TicTacToeApi(remote.Service):

@endpoints.method(request_message=StubMessageIn,
                  response_message=StubMessageIn,
                  path='stub2',
                  name='stub_method_2',
                  http_method='POST')
def stub_it2(self, request):
    return request

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([TicTacToeApi],
                               restricted=False)
```

Here's the HTML  & JS:

```
<body>
<script>
    function do_it() {
        var form1 = document.getElementById('f1');
        var input1 = document.getElementById("tell_me");
        var data1 = input1.value;
        var data2 = "?tell_me=" + data1 ;
        var url1 = "http://localhost:16080/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/stub2";
        console.log("Going to: " + url1 + data2);
        form1.method = "POST";
        form1.action = url1 + data2;
        form1.removeChild(input1)
        form1.submit()
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="do_it();"
    name = f1
    id = f1>
    <input type='text' name = 'tell_me' id = 'tell_me'>
    <input type='submit' value = "Submit -w- JS">
</form>

<form method="POST"
    action = "http://localhost:16080/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/stub2?tell_me=thursday" >
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit no JS">
</form>
</body>
```

Here's the app.yaml:

```
application: fsndp4-tic-tac-toe-01
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Static assets
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /
  static_files: templates/index.html
  upload: templates/index\.html
  secure: always

# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: tictactoe_api.APPLICATION
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origins: *

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest

- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Here's what the rendered HTML looks like in Chrome

[image: Rendered HTML]

Here's the response when it's all working; assuming you put "Ham and Eggs" into the text input:

```
{
 "tell_me": "Ham and Eggs"
}
```

I hope that's a little more clear than mud ... Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleeping on things helps ... One answer to the second question is to move the text input outside the form. Here's the new HTML:

```
<body>
        <script>
            function do_it() {
                var form1 = document.getElementById('f1');
                var input1 = document.getElementById("tell_me");
                var data1 = input1.value;
                var data2 = "?tell_me=" + data1 ;
                var url1 = "http://localhost:16080/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/stub2";
                console.log("Going to: " + url1 + data2);
                form1.method = "POST";
                form1.action = url1 + data2;
                // form1.removeChild(input1)
                form1.submit()
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <!--
        Move tell_me text input out of the form so it does not
        need to be removed prior to submitting the form.
        Formatting can be solved with an HTML table later
         -->

        <input type='text' name = 'tell_me' id = 'tell_me'>

        <form onsubmit="do_it();"
              name = f1
              id = f1>
            <input type='submit' value = "Submit -w- JS">
        </form>


        <form method="POST"
                action = "http://localhost:16080/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/stub2?tell_me=thursday" >
            <input type="submit" value = "Submit no JS">
        </form>
</body>
```

Note that I just commented out the `form1.removeChild(input1)` for clarity between the two examples.

This cleans things up enough for what I was trying to do. I'm considering this one answered. Any additional info on how the Endpoint API works is always appreciated of course.